# `adb pull` says it pulled all of the files from my Android phone into my Windows PC, but in reality it didn't

Tags: adb, backup, windows

So I am using `adb` to copy all of my Android files to my Windows PC with this command: `adb pull -a /mnt/sdcard C:\backup`

And when it's done it says all x amount of files have been pulled, I can confirm that the number of pulled files matches the amount of files that reside inside the folder of my Android storage but when I check how many files are actually in the `C:\backup` folder, I see about 200 missing or in other words adb skipped about 200 files and did not copy them over to my `C:\backup` folder.

I understand that this could be due to [path limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) or due to some files containing characters in their filenames that Windows' NTFS file system just doesn't allow.

How can I see what files are actually being skipped? Is there a switch in `adb` or some trick?

Comment: You can instead use tar on device to create a tar archive with all files and stream that to your PC. May be tar works more reliable: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/194854/2241 If you device is not rooted remove the `su` part and adapt the path.

Comment: @Robert I used `adb exec-out 'tar c /storage/emulated/0/123.txt' > 123.tar` but it just creates a corrupted tar archive.

Comment: @alecxs `/mnt/sdcard/` is internal storage and it is also the same as `/storage/emulated/0` and no, I am not trying to pull things from a MicroSD, I am trying to pull all the files in the internal storage's root directory.

Comment: The tar archive was corrupted (what type of corruption)? May be you are facing a totally different problem with a broken USB cable and/or port. What adb version do you use the latest from Android SDK?

Comment: @Robert No matter what file or how many files I add to the tar archive with that command it always outputs a 90 byte archive that 7z can't open because it says "Is not archive". I am using the latest adb, I literally downloaded it today. Tried multiple USB cables, same issue.

Comment: Seems like tar has some problems with the absolute path (it then outputs some text which destroys the archive) also you used the wrong quotes. This works: `adb exec-out "cd /sdcard && tar c *" > sdcard.tar`

Comment: `*` does not match all file names use `.` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pulling all files via adb to a Windows computer has multiple problems:

1. Android/Linux allows multiple files in one directory that just differ in their case.
2. The file system on Linux allows characters in file and directory names that are disallowed on Windows.
3. Some file names are completely disallowed on Windows which are just regular file names on Linux/Android.
4. There is a path limit as you have already mentioned that may cause trouble.

Hence, the best solution to create a full backup of the SD card is to pack all files into one tar archive as all file system limitations of Windows can be bypassed using this method.

Via adb, you create a full backup of the SD card using the following command:

```
adb exec-out "cd /storage/emulated/0 && tar c * -" > sdcard.tar
```

This command creates the tar archive on the device and directly streams the data of the tar archive through adb to your PC and saves it there as `sdcard.tar`.

**WARNING:** The created file `sdcard.tar` will be corrupt if `tar` prints any warning or error message to stdout (this will be invisible to the user executing the command). Therefore, it is crucial to perform an integrity check on the created tar file if the tar structures and the contained files are correct. For more details, see this answer to [ADB pull stops after first error](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233784/2241).

Comment: @alexs You are correct 1 is not possible but 2 and 3 are valid. Filenames with backslash are possible and reserved names like aux and com1 are also possible just as an example.

Comment: oh no how stupid from sdcardfs. thought behavior is same as vfat

Comment: I wish this worked, but I simply get a corrupted tar archive no matter what.

Comment: @computationalprince But the tar size should be correct, yes? Use an hex editor to check if the file starts with an error message.

Comment: @Robert I just noticed that `tar` doesn't exist in `/system/bin` folder but I have `tar` installed in [Termux](https://termux.com/) but I can't execute it in adb because I don't have permission.

Comment: @computationalprince An Android without tar installed, ok that explains a lot. What device do you use (manufacturer, model and Android version)? In termux you should be able to copy busybox/tar to `/data/local` or `/data/local/tmp`. From there you can execute it from adb.

Comment: @Robert My phone is a Huawei G8 with Android 5.1.1 and I don't have permission on `/data/local` nor `/data/local/tmp` althought I can `cd` into both of them.

Comment: @computationalprince Right, access to that folders is only possible via adb. Hence if you really want a warking tar you have to copy the busybox binary to sdcard in Termux. Them in adb copy it from sdcard to `/data/local/tmp` and restore the executable flag via chmod. Then you can execute tar via `/data/local/tmp/busybox tar`.

Comment: @Robert You were right! I did everything you said and now when I run your command with the new `tar` path e.g. `adb exec-out "cd /storage/emulated/0 && /data/local/tmp/busybox tar c * -" > sdcard.tar` I get a healthy tar archive with all the files. Thank you a lot!