# How to log errors when using adb pull?

Tags: adb, backup, logging, troubleshooting

I am using the latest version of `adb` with the `pull` command to backup my data.

Sometimes `adb pull` doesn't backup all of my files, so I am trying to figure out which files have not been backed up.

Using `adb logcat -f logcat.txt bugreport pull "my path" "my path 2"` just throws me a `create bugreport fail!` and `create bugreports dir error!!`. I've tried multiple directories with full permission but with no luck.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The presented command is a mixture of two ADB commands which AFAIK does not work. Execute them individually each in one console.

Comment: try [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) or [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute an `adb pull` comand and at the same time monitor the on-device log via `adb logcat` you can do so by executing each command individually in it's own terminal/cmd.exe instance.

`adb` is not limited to a single connection (as the MTP protocol is). Hence you can execute two or more adb command simultaneously. Even multiple adb push or pull commands can be executed at the same time.

However I doubt that doing so will get you much insight regarding your problem with `adb pull` that [some files are not copied via adb pull](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225295). The main problem is that `adb logcat` just displays the log of your device. All errors on adb level, for example if a file could not created on your PC or transmission problems between device and PC are not covered by this log as the device does not know about them.

Additionally I am not sure that the on-device adb daemon writes messages to the logcat log at all.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `logcat` and `pull` being two different commands. My bad.

Comment: @computationalprince adb can be seen as some sort of ssh connection that connects to the device and executes commands commands on-device (e.g. `logcat` is simply a binary that is executed on-device). Only in case of file transmissions some additional logic (pull/push/install) for the file transfer is executed by adb itself.