# How to transfer files from PC to Android via wifi without special software?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, google-pixel

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11 came out in late 2020, when most home networks use wifi.

After searching for hours, I have been unable to find a built-in way of transferring files from my Windows PC to my Android Pixel (and ideally the reverse too) without downloading a special app from the Play store.

This is shocking to me.

Is it really the case that Android doesn't natively support wifi file transfer?

[I'd rather not need to search for (and decide whether I trust) a third-party app. And I'd certainly rather not use a physical cable for file transfers like it's 1990.]

Comment: There's nothing like "native wifi file transfer" exists. You need to have a file transfer protocol. Windows natively supports SMB/CIFS over network, Linux does NFS. Android's native way is MTP (over USB) or ADB (over USB or network). Or simply use some other open-source protocol like FTP/SFTP or one of the many proprietary protocols file transfer apps use. Depending on your choice you need to use proper server and/or client software on both sides. In case of Windows a simple file explorer Android app with CIFS support will serve your need. You may try MiXplorer.

Comment: The only built-in file-exchange system I know if file transfer via Bluetooth (which is limited regarding the supported file types). Smartphones are not designed to exchange data in local networks - a large number of smartphone users don't even have a local PC they could sync something to. Instead smartphones are focused on syncing itself with cloud services like GDrive.

Comment: [adb over wifi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) is native since android 11. [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) required on PC. transfer with adb push/[pull](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226573)