# How to upgrade Pixel 3's internal storage to more than 64 GB

Tags: internal-storage, google-pixel, google-pixel-3

I have a Pixel 3 that has been fine, but its 64 GB internal storage frequently gets full, and I don't like needing to connect the device to my computer with a physical cable (it [blows my mind](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234329/22600) that it's 2022 and I'm still using cables for file transfer) and move files to my PC just to free up space on my phone to keep is usable.

I see that there were versions of the phone that featured [128 GB](https://amzn.to/33puZAn) of storage.

How could I buy a >=128 GB internal card (or whatever it's called) and install it in my device, replacing the 64 GB one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pixel 3 does not have a slot for inserting an Micro-SD card. Therefore you can not upgrade your device.

The 64GB memory chip is built-in soldered to the main board of the phone. Replacing it is next to impossible.

The only workaround would be using an USB flash memory stick with USB-C connectors (or an USB-A version + adapter cable) and manually copy data from/to the flash memory stick.

But I would not recommend doing so as it increases the chance to break your USB port making it in the end impossible to charge without wireless charger.