# Lenovo - Internal Storage and SD-Card empty (on device and pc)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, lenovo

As stated above.
Someone asks me to help him with his phone.
I have no clue what happened, I never heard about thats happening before, soo.. yeah...

The phone is an Lenovo with Android 6.0.
It has an 16Gb SD-Card.

Since a couple of days the pictures weren't accessable. So my friend brought the phone to me.
When going to the Data Manager (The "App" where you can see all file of internal/external storage) it says "Empty" while trieing to view the internal storage.
It doesn't even recognize the SD-Card.

Same goes when I look at the phone from my PC (via USB).

The phone still works. WhatsApp still works, but is unable to make BackUps because of "No Internal Storage detected".

Is there anything I can do? The last BackUp of whatsapp is corrupted and I would hate to have to tell my friend that all the pictures, WhatsApp Chats, etc. is gone.

Thanks for everyone trying to help.

**EDIT 1:**
The variables are filled as followed:
External_Storage = /sdcard
Android_Storage = /storage

**EDIT 2:**
The find cmd on "/storage" and "/sdcard" works I think.
I get a very long list of files and folders, but I get  "Permission denied" on "./data", "./root", "./dev", "./init" and some other folders. (I guess that's because I haven't rooted the device?)

Comment: Test the SD-card in an USB SD-card read on a PC and check e.g. in Windows if Diskmanager recognizes the card at all. If not the card is most likely defect.

Comment: @Robert the diskmanager recognizes it as "F:" but no Volume (not empty not used, just nothing). But at the same time the internal storage is empty too, so how can that happen? Because the phone is still running and can even be rebootet.

Comment: @alecxs WhatsApp was only an excample to state that Apps mostly work. Except when they have to load something from the internal storage/sd-card. I cant look up photos with the media app, can't create backups from whatsapp, but the apart from that everything still works. And that is whats confusing me. How can everything still work, when nothing can access the Internal Storage/the internal Storage is corrupted?

Also I have no clue how to check both the variables. I  never did stuff with android before other than using it.

Comment: @alecxs Updated the question, Sorry that it took so long :/

Comment: you can backup Internal Storage `/sdcard` and MicroSD Card `/storage/1A2B-3C4D` via `adb pull` https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226573

Comment: `adb backup` does not work for WhatsApp. However there is solution to downgrade WhatsApp to [older](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-whatsapp-key-db-extractor-crypt6-12-non-root-updated-october-2016.2770982/page-30) version which allows backup. be careful don't forget `-k` flag when uninstalling (keep data)