# Why does "tar -czh" produce a corrupt archive but "tar -ch | gzip" work fine?

Tags: adb, backup

I am trying to backup a directory from a phone over `adb`.

When using the following command I get an archive which is corrupt:

```
adb exec-out "tar -czh /sdcard/DCIM" > backup.tar.gz
```

[image]

But with the following command the archive is correct:

```
adb exec-out "tar -ch /sdcard/DCIM | gzip" > backup.tar.gz
```

The two tar files are 48.8mB with a difference of about 200kB. The corrupt archive is smaller.

I am using `adb` at the Windows command line. It is necessary to receive the output as compressed data to avoid newline conversions. Both commands should provide compressed data.

My question is specifically asking why these two commands which should be identical are producing a different result.

The phone is running LineageOS 14.1 and is connected to a computer running Windows 10.

Comment: Unwanted terminal characters (printing or non-printing) may get included in the output which corrupt the archive. Use `stty raw` or `dos2unix`. See details under **ADB** heading in my answer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526

Comment: Is there a way to disable stderr redirecting when using `adb exec-out` to avoid such problems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB pull stops after first error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error)

Comment: FWIW, I also tried both commands (1 folder containing 1 image file) and both files were deemed invalid archives by 7zip. Opening them with Notepad++ (yeah, not the best tool, but worked nevertheless) shown them as binary with no readable text/error output appended.

Comment: @alecxs The archive as described in the question that was not corrupt works fine and the images are well formed.

Answer (score 1):

`exec-out` mixed up stdout and stderr

in 1st example the tar `stderr` message *"removing leading '/' from member names"* is redirected into target file

in 2nd example only tar `stdout` is piped to `gzip`

to avoid broken archive silent `stderr` see linked duplicate

Comment: \*2nd `gzip` *stdout + stderr* still mixed (but there is no)