# Why would Android list some files that are not accessible (I/O error)?

Tags: adb, shell, system, files

For background, trying to resolve a problem with a Android 4.x tablet Denver TAC-97032 ([Tablet battery replacement and alloc_device_open fail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239013/tablet-battery-replacement-and-alloc-device-open-fail)).

The device cannot boot fully, but I can connect to it via `adb`.

After finding [Android boot-up messages for debugging?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26123/android-boot-up-messages-for-debugging), first I tried `./adb pull //proc/kmsg` (doubled slash due to MSYS2 bash); and there I could see:

```
<3>[    9.696137] init: cannot find '/system/bin/bootanimation', disabling 'bootanim'
<7>[   12.967235] WRN:L1364(drivers/usb/sun4i_usb/udc/sw_udc.c):handle_ep0: ep0 setup end
<7>[   92.223978] battery vol change: 59->60
```

Hmm... so I thought to check:

```
root@android:/ # ls /system/bin/bootanimation
ls /system/bin/bootanimation
/system/bin/bootanimation: I/O error
```

Weird - so I thought to check the listing of `/system/bin` as plain, vs listing with `-la`; and you can see the result of this compare in `meld` (note, I manually removed timestamps from the `-la` output for easier comparison):

[image: meld_compare_system_bin]

So, there is a whole bunch of files (thankfully, all grouped together, so all of them are shown on the screenshot), that plain `ls` lists - but `ls -la` doesn't!

What is the explanation for this behavior? How could Android possibly get those filenames to begin with, if they are not accessible? And is there anything I could do, to make the inaccessible files accessible?