# Copy photos to new Samsung Galaxy S22 and maintain time/date stamps

Tags: photos, date-and-time

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy S22 running Android 12. I'm moving the photos from the microSD card in the Samsung Galaxy S10e (of course they removed the SD card slot in the S22) to the S22.

I did it first using SmartSwitch, but it changed all the Modified dates to today. So, then I tried zipping the files, moving the zip to the S22, and unzipping it using the Files app from Google. Again, it changed the dates to today even though inside the zip file the dates were all correct.

Any ideas here on how to maintain time/date stamps?

Comment: https://siongui.github.io/2021/11/15/copy-file-to-android-preserve-timestamp/

Comment: https://appuals.com/how-to-transfer-photos-between-android-devices-without-losing-timestamps/

Comment: *adb pull `-a` / adb push `-sync`* flags should preserve file timestamp, but I recommend *adb exec-out `tar`*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB pull stops after first error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error)