# adb push/pull as root

Tags: adb, root-access

`adb pull` and `adb push` can be used to transfer files from and to the device via the ADB connection.

However, even on a rooted device, these commands seem to operate with user permissions. I can access anything on `/sdcard`, but when I try to push to, say, `/data`, the operation fails due to lack of permissions.

Of course, I can push the file to a different location, then `adb shell` into the device, run `su` to become root, and then copy the file to its final destination – but that is a kludgy workaround, not a real solution.

Also, I can install an SSH server on the device which runs as root and use SSH to copy the files over, but I am wondering if ADB offers something similar natively.

Is there any way I can get `adb push`/`adb pull` to operate with root privileges on the device?

Comment: The reason for this behavior is that `adbd` is by default compiled in "secure mode" which means it is started with root permissions but after start-up it drops it's root permissions. So the only way to change this is to replace or modify the `adbd` binary included in the installed ROM.

Comment: I see that `adbd` runs as a non-privileged user, as does any process it spawns. That includes shell sessions – however, if enabled on the device, I can then run `su` from that shell session to obtain root privileges. So you’re saying that `adbd` does not have any built-in functionality for doing that and/or the ADB wire protocol lacks the means to specify whether an operation is to be carried out in privileged mode?

Comment: Yes, `adbd` runs as non-privileged user, but it is started with root permissions (which is then dropped after start-up). ssh is running always with root permissions and if a user connects the shell process is executed as the user which has logged-in. adbd can not do somethin similar because it has dropped root permissions after start-up and also adbd is not designed to run a shell or a file-transfer session as a different user, so adb always has the permissions adbd runs with.

Comment: If [`adb root`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526) works on your device, it'll make `adbd` run with UID 0.

Comment: you can use exec-out or exec-in with su `-c` flag, similar to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226573). or push files to /data/local/tmp and then move them

Comment: a workaround not requiring intermediary copies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74666297/191246